# Travis-CI is not listing the Github branch although it is whitelisted

Tags: git, travis-ci

I am using Travis for CI/CD. It is expected that builds should be run only on master and develop branches. To do so, I have whitelisted these two branches in `.travis.yml` file. This file is available under both the branches. I am facing the weird scenario that `master` branch is listed in travis but `develop` doesn't. Here is whitelisting configuration.

```
language: android
sudo: required

branches:
  only:
    - develop
    - master
```

[image]

Comment: What's the repo? What branches *do* exist?

Comment: I am working on a private Github repo. I have cross checked and made sure that both `develop` and `master` branches are available and active.

Comment: Are there only three branches, though; develop, master and the one you've censored? Or are there other branches not shown in the drop down? Given that it's a beta feature, you might be better off talking to Travis support.

Comment: There are other branches too but I need only master and develop to be listed. There is one other branch too which is getting listed. I have removed travis.yml file from that branch. Still it is visible.